# Denominator intractability in Bayesian inference

Tags: statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

It can often be read that Bayesian inference i.e. using Bayes theorem, to compute the posterior i.e.:

$p(\theta|x)$, with $\theta$ a continuous random variable (and possibly $x$ too)

can be intractable, i.e., non computable,because of the integral at the denominator.

However, it seems to me that if the numerator would be computable, then we can sum over many values of $\theta$, e.g. like "grid approximation" and then divide by this sum to normalize.

i.e. the whole thing  (continuous) Bayes theorem:

$p(\theta|x)=\frac{p(x|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int_{\Theta} p(x,u)du}$

where $\theta \in \Theta$

Or are we talking only about computing the analytical form of the intergal i.e. antiderivarive and get a closed form?

Sometimes e.g. for MLE or MAP one can ignore the denominator abd compute the likelihood as e.g. the product (or sum of logs, loglikelihood)...
but i guess the problem is that if we want a **distribution**,  i.e. the posterior distribution and **not a point estimate** as the MLE or MAP then we would need to then evaluate it at an infinite number of values of continuous $\theta$ and then - if we could do that   which we can't of course - then sum and divide by that  (which is of course the integral) ... just is that an "intuitive" way to say it?

I would just like someone to validate and/or possibly reformulate this  statement and possibly develop a bit...

Comment: "However, it seems to me that if thr numerator would be computable, then we can sum over many values of θ, e.g. like 'grid approximation' " : Agreed.  In fact, in *days of yore*, prior to 1500 AD, this is exactly how Mathematicians attacked what was (in effect) integration problems.  They got *Reimann-Sum-rectangle-happy*.  It could be argued that Calculus was invented because too many Mathematicians were overdosing on rectangles.

Comment: yes lol.. you know that it is said often that this integral is intractable in Bayesian stuff and they mention the  (infinite?) "combinatorics"cost  due to continuous theta  (which could be a vector of parameters).... so do they mean that these integrals often do NOT have a computable - analytical i mean - antiderivative i.e. a formula in which one could plug values?

Comment: as you pointed out you usually can "ignore" the denominator because this is a constant which is consistent when you take logs. Depends on what you need to do, alternatively if you have a simple enough model (analytical distributions that are complimentary) then you can compute it through integration etc.